# How to map properties in EF CTP5

Tags: entity-framework-4, entity-framework-ctp5

In CTP 4 we could choose the properties we want to map like so:

```
    this.MapSingleType(i => new
{
    i.Id,
    i.OriginalFileName,
    i.Extension,
    i.MimeType,
    i.Width,
    i.Height,
    i.ImageStoreLocationId,
    i.AlternateText,
    i.ImageData
});
```

How do we achieve this in CTP5?

I tried using the following Map configuration but this does not appear to work since I still have to explicitly ignore (this.Ignore(..)) the properties I do not wish to map:

```
    Map(config =>
{
    config.Properties(i => new
    {
        i.OriginalFileName,
        i.Extension,
        i.MimeType,
        i.Width,
        i.Height,
        i.ImageStoreLocationId,
        i.AlternateText,
        i.ImageData
    });

    config.ToTable("Images");
});
```

Considering the new API is supposed to be more fluent, it's strange that I have to write more code to achieve the same thing.

Thanks
Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CTP5 is indeed more powerful and flexible both in Data Annotations and fluent API. For example in CTP4 if we wanted to exclude a property from mapping we would have to explicitly map *everything else* with *MapSingleType* in order to skip the one we don't want, like the way you mentioned.

 
In CTP5 this can be done simply by using `[NotMapped]` attribute on the property or by this fluent API code:

```
this.Ignore(i => i.Id);
```

And you are done, no need to invoke `Map` method.

Comment: yes I realize I can ignore properties like this. Can I no longer map a group of properties like I used to? In some cases this is preferable rather than relying on conventions.

Comment: Ah, now I see what you mean. Yes, you are right, seems like you have to explicitly ignore the property or it will complain. With having `[NotMapped]` attribute, that's not so bad IMHO.

Answer (score 5):

This blog post has ctp 5 mapping samples.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/12/14/ef-feature-ctp5-fluent-api-samples.aspx

Make a clr-nullable property required:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>() 
    .Property(p => p.Name) 
    .IsRequired();
```

Change string length:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>() 
    .Property(p => p.Name) 
    .HasMaxLength(50);
```

Switch off Identity:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>() 
    .Property(p => p.ProductId) 
    .HasDatabaseGenerationOption(DatabaseGenerationOption.None);
```

Ignore a property:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>() 
    .Ignore(p => p.Name);
```

Table & Column Mapping
Change column name:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Category>() 
    .Property(c => c.Name) 
    .HasColumnName("cat_name");
```

Change table name:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Category>() 
    .ToTable("MyCategories");
```

Change table name with schema:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Category>() 
    .ToTable("MyCategories", "sales");
```

Comment: Yes I have seen this article but it does not explain how to map a group of properties. In this case I do not want to rely on conventions to map my class.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by a group of properties? If you need to map properties the new api is 
modelBuilder.Entity<Category>() 
    .Property(c => c.Name) 
    .HasColumnName("cat_name");